# ActionScript 3 Text Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, actionscript

I'm unsure why this error is produced as it works perfectly before slide 5.

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at rlo_fla::Question_15/updateTextFunction()[rlo_fla.Question_15::frame1:17]
    at Main/frame6()[Main::frame6:31]
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at Main/Answer()[Main::frame5:44]

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main/clickInfoLoopFunction()[/Users/Kristian/Dropbox/University of Westminster/RLO/Project/Main.as:238]
```

The .fla and .as are available on my git: https://github.com/EpicKris/rlo

I'm sorry I can't provide much more insight, I'm just incredibly unsure of the nature of the problem.

Comment: In the referenced method updateTextFunction() are you assigning something.text = avariable; at some point, this error would indicate you are and avariable=null at the time.

Comment: @shaunhusain That's exactly what I'm doing, however the variable is not null as all the variables are declared at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In the function clickInfoLoopFunction(), you call:

```
infoMC.updateTextFunction(textO['Topic ' + currentTopicI + ' Slide ' + currentSlideI + ' Info']);
```

The problem is that the value of either currentTopicI or currentSlideI became something unexpected, and tried to access a property that doesn't exist in textO. If you run into this error again, trace the output of currentTopicI and currentSlideI right before this line. Then you'll figure out that, for example, the program was trying to call textO['Topic928Slide-5Info']. Of course, after that you'll have to figure out *why* those values changed unexpectedly, but this is a start.

**EDIT**
: There are two main problems

1) You have a number of MovieClips in the FLA with functions in them to update text in a TextField. Right now they try to set the text even if the parameter is null. So prevent that by wrapping the text-setting lines with:

```
if (theParameter != null) { }
```

2) In Main.as, in the function clickInfoLoopFunction(), infoMC.updateTextFunction(textO['... gets called, but sometimes infoMC itself is null, so only call this function when infoMC exists:

```
if (infoMC) infoMC.updateTextFunction(textO['Topic ' + currentTopicI + ' Slide ' + currentSlideI + ' Info']);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure why you're not seeing this error, I follow the steps below and am always getting the same error. Even after clearing all caches.

To reproduce this error:
`Continue` > `Significant Figures & Decimal Places` > `Information` > `Questions` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Question` > `Answer` > `Information` > `Information`

Comment: What I don't understand is that looping through any 'Info' slides works fine before the questions and on the second topic, so why is it messing up after the questions on the first topic. Also I checked the `currentTopicI` and `currentSlideI` which were returned as 1 and 5 (respectively) which is correct.

Comment: I see. Okay, there are two things you need to do to fix this. You have some MovieClips in your FLA that sets the text of a text label on the stage, like Question, Answer, Info, etc. Right now, they are trying to set the text even if it is null, which Flash is currently throwing errors about. So step 1 is to wrap the line where you set text around: if (textS != null) { ... }. Step 2, put 'if (infoMC) ' in front of the line I quoted above (infoMC.updateTextFunction(textO['...). For some reason, infoMC disappears sometimes, so this will only set text if infoMC exists.

Comment: I understand that I could wrap the `updateTextFunction`s in an if statement or try, catch block. However the way it's setup, that specific slide _should_ include `infoMC`, but for some (unknown to me) reason it moves to one of the question slides and thus there's no `infoMC`, so although that would get rid of my error, it does not solve the problem because it wouldn't produce anything on the screen.